# How does one perform the Fligner-Policello test in SAS using NPAR1WAY?

Tags: statistics, sas

My questions is about the SAS procedure NPAR1WAY. Specifically, I want to use the Fligner-Policello test, which is supposed to be invoked through the "FP" option. This test is an adjustment to the standard Wilcoxon rank-sum test for two-samples.

This option is documented on the SAS help website; however, no examples are given. I have not been able to find any examples of proper syntax for using this test.

Here is the syntax that I have tried so far and which seems to be suggested by the SAS documentation:

```
proc npar1way fp data=input;
    class stratum;
    var varname;
run;
```

Here is the error message:

```
R 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ;, AB, ALPHA, ANOVA, CONOVER, CORRECT, D, DATA, EDF, HL, KLOTZ, KS,
              KS1, MEDIAN, MISSING, MOOD, NOPRINT, NORMAL, PERM, PLOTS, SAVAGE, SCORES, ST, VW, WILCOXON.
ERROR 202-322: The option or parameter is not recognized and will be ignored.
```

The error message seems to suggest that SAS is not expecting the "fp" option, yet the SAS documentation does mention it (http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/66859/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_npar1way_details20.htm).

Has anybody used this test before successfully?

Answer (score 0):

You reference the documentation for SAS/STAT 13.1, in which the `FP` option is documented and supported. However, based on what SAS is telling you it expects in the `PROC NPAR1WAY` statement, it looks like you don't have SAS/STAT 13.1. The `FP` option was new to 12.1, the release prior to 13.1, before which it was not available. (See [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/65328/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_whatsnew_sect025.htm) for the enhancements introduced to `NPAR1WAY` in 12.1.)

So how do you get the Fligner-Policello test from `NPAR1WAY` in your version? If you have a version of SAS/STAT prior to 12.1, unfortunately you can't, at least not directly.